# psql seems to timeout with long queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, psql

I am performing a bulk copy into postgres with about 80GB of data.

```
\copy my_table FROM '/path/csv_file.csv' csv DELIMITER ','
```

Before the transaction is committed I get the following error.

> Server closed the connection unexpectedly
>       This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>       before or while processing the request.

In the PostgreSQL logs:

```
LOG:server process (PID 21122) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
LOG:terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT: In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
```

Comment: Is the copy running on the local host or via a remote connection? I'd say you're seeing a backend crash personally. Check the PostgreSQL error logs for details. If you have very high `work_mem` or `maintenance_work_mem` maybe you're running out of memory? Or maybe you're running out of disk space - though that should generally produce a better error. Also what's the exact PostgreSQL version, anyway?

Comment: The version is 8.4.11. I'm running it on a remote machine. I'm ssh'd into the box but i'm using 'screen'. I do see this in the logs " Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments""

Comment: just to clarify, `psql` is running on the same machine as the database? It doesn't matter if it's remote to you, only if it's remote to the `psql` client or not; if you're using `psql` to talk to a database on `localhost` it won't be a networking issue.

Comment: Look for the point the client disconnected in the logs; search for `FATAL` or `PANIC` level messages.

Comment: LOG:server process (PID 21122) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
LOG:terminating any other active server processes WARNING:terminating connection because of crash of another server process DETAIL:The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, beca         use another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory. HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your backend process receiving a signal 9 (`SIGKILL`). This can happen if:

- Somebody sends a `kill -9` manually;
- A cron job is set up to send `kill -9` under some circumstances (very unsafe, do not do this); or
- the Linux out-of-memory (OOM) killer triggers and terminates the process.

In the latter case you will see reports of OOM killer activity in the kernel's `dmesg` output. I expect this is what you'll see in your case.

PostgreSQL servers should be configured without virtual memory overcommit so that the OOM killer does not run and PostgreSQL can handle out-of-memory conditions its self. See [the PostgreSQL documentation on Linux memory overcommit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT).

The separate question "why is this using so much memory" remains. Answering that requires more knowledge of your setup: how much RAM the server has, how much of it is free, what your `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem` settings are, etc. It isn't a very interesting problem to look into until you *upgrade to the current PostgreSQL 8.4 patch release* to make sure the problem isn't one that's already fixed.

Comment: Upgrading to postgres 9.1 did the trick, seems like a 8.4 issue. Thanks again for the help Craig.

Comment: @MattE Or an old-8.4-patch-release problem. You should generally try to keep up with the patches, eg should really have been running 8.4.17 not 8.4.11. This is important for security, performance, reliability, etc.